# redmine 2.4 installation on 14.04 fails on bundle install

Tags: 14.04, redmine

I'm trying to set up redmine (locally) using kubuntu 14.04, and followed the instructions [from redmine.org](http://www.redmine.org/projects/redmine/wiki/RedmineInstall). Installing redmine 2.4.2 from the Kubuntu repositories works fine. Then I also did `sudo apt-get install bundler` and `sudo gem install bundler`. But then I am supposed to run `bundle install --without development test`, which fails with the message `Bundler::GemfileNotFound`.

More specifically, `bundle install --verbose --without development test` gives the following output

```
Bundler::GemfileNotFound
Bundler::GemfileNotFound: Bundler::GemfileNotFound
/usr/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/bundler/settings.rb:16:in `[]='
/usr/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/bundler/settings.rb:79:in `without='
/usr/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/bundler/cli.rb:237:in `install'
/usr/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/thor/command.rb:27:in `run'
/usr/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/thor/invocation.rb:121:in `invoke_command'
/usr/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/thor.rb:363:in `dispatch'
/usr/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/thor/base.rb:440:in `start'
/usr/bin/bundle:20:in `block in <main>'
/usr/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/bundler/friendly_errors.rb:3:in `with_friendly_errors'
/usr/bin/bundle:20:in `<main>'
```

Then what can I do?

Comment: CC into the directory that has `Gemfile`

Comment: Thanks! That seemed to do the trick (although I did have to run bundle as root, which it says I shouldn't do).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Locate where 'Gemfile' is. CC into that directory and run

```
bundle install --without development test
```